# Connection to TFS Server from Visual Studio and also TFS Admin Console Change Public URL test throwing error TF400324

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2018

We have a public facing URL (F5 load balancer URL) and internal application URL for TFS 2018 Update3.2 server host on prem. Both URLs were working fine when accessed from Visual Studio all version from local machine/laptop. Recently all of a sudden public facing URL stopped working when accessed from Visual studio. Its throwing error **"TF400324: team foundation services are not available from server technical information for administrator: the underlying connection was closed: an unexpected error occured on a receive"**.
We are able to access same public facing URL from web browser and users are able to create and update issues from web browser with out any issues. The only issue is accessing it from Visual Studio.
I logged into TFS Server to test public URL setting in TFS Admin Console to check if accessing issue is also reproducible on TFS Server itself. I found that issue is reproducible on TFS Server using TFS Admin Console. When trying to test the public URL using TFS Admin Console i am getting same error **"TF400324: team foundation services are not available from server technical information for administrator: the underlying connection was closed: an unexpected error occured on a receive"**.
No logs on Event Viewer when testing public URL on TFS Admin Console. Tried to clear cache on client side with no help. Need help to resolve this issue. [Error on TFS Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxPFq.png)

Comment: Please try the following steps:
  1. Close all Visual Studio instances.
  2.Clean the TFS cache folder. The folder path is: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\{version}\Cache
  3. Restart IIS and application pool
  4. Restart your Visual Studio to re-connect to your TFS Server.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working. Please let me know if i have to do anything else

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you change your public URL and  test the new public URL?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot change the public URL because this is production instance.

Comment: It looks like this problem is related to TLS. Have you enabled TLS 1.2 or change TLS settings on your Team Foundation Server machine recently? Please try the solution in [this document](https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2016/02/28/pci-compliant-web-deploy-getting-webdeploy-working-after-disabling-insecure-ciphers-like-ssl-30-and-tls-10).